# C# Linq over XML => Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I have an xml document which consists of a number of the following:

```
- <LabelFieldBO>
  <Height>23</Height> 
  <Width>100</Width> 
  <Top>32</Top> 
  <Left>128</Left> 
  <FieldName>field4</FieldName> 
  <Text>aoi_name</Text> 
  <DataColumn>aoi_name</DataColumn> 
  <FontFamily>Arial</FontFamily> 
  <FontStyle>Regular</FontStyle> 
  <FontSize>8.25</FontSize> 
  <Rotation>0</Rotation> 
  <LabelName /> 
  <LabelHeight>0</LabelHeight> 
  <LabelWidth>0</LabelWidth> 
  <BarCoded>false</BarCoded> 
  </LabelFieldBO>
```

I have figured out how to find the element where LabelName = 'container'.  But I am not well versed with lambda expressions and would like to know how to access the information within my LINQ results.  Lambda expressions may not be the way to go either.  I am open to any suggestions.

```
var dimensions = from field in xml.Elements("LabelFieldBO")
                             where field.Element("LabelName").Value == "container"
                             select field;
```

Thanks.

EDIT: What I am trying to figure out is how to get the LabelHeight and LabelWidth out of the XML where LabelName = "container"

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you want to do, could you please describe it a bit more exact. Possible with samples of the results that you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from field in xml.Elements("LabelFieldBO")  
where field.Element("LabelName").Value == "container"  
select new   
{  
    LabelHeight = field.Element("LabelHeight").Value,  
    LabelWidth = field.Element("LabelWidth").Value  
}
```

This returns an IEnumerable of anonymous types with two properties (LabelWeight and LabelWidth).  Each object in the IEnumerable represents a LabelFieldB0 with LabelName = "container".

So, you can "get at" your data doing something like:

```
var containerLabels =   
    from field in xml.Elements("LabelFieldBO")  
    where field.Element("LabelName").Value == "container"  
    select new   
    {  
        LabelHeight = field.Element("LabelHeight").Value,  
        LabelWidth = field.Element("LabelWidth").Value  
    } 

foreach (var containerLabel in containerLabels)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(containerLabel.LabelHeight + " "
        + containerLabel.LabelWidth);  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code create a new anonymous object that contains the label name, width, and height.

```
var result = doc.Elements("LabelFieldBo")
                 .Where(x => x.Element("LabelName").Value == "container")
                 .Select(x =>
                     new { 
                         Name = x.Element("LabelName").Value,
                         Height = x.Element("LabelHeight").Value,
                         Width = x.Element("LabelWidth").Value
                 }
             );
```